# Select a random card from list in python

Tags: python, random

so I need to make a "game" where the user is ask if he wants to select a card and if yes, then a random card will be returned. something like this:

```
>>>selectCard()
Would you like to draw a random card? (yes/no)
The card you got is: 8 of hearts
Would you like to draw a random card? (yes/no)
>>>yes
The card you got is: Ace of diamonds
Would you like to draw a random card? (yes/no)
>>>no
```

so far I have this but I am stuck and don't know how to finish it

```
def selectCards():
cardranks = ['Ace',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'Jack','Queen','King','Ace',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'Jack','Queen','King','Ace',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'Jack','Queen','King','Ace',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'Jack','Queen','King']
cardsuits = ['of Clubs','of Clubs','of Clubs','of Clubs','of Clubs','of Clubs','of Clubs','of Clubs','of Clubs','of Clubs','of Clubs','of Clubs','of Clubs','of Diamonds','of Diamonds','of Diamonds','of Diamonds','of Diamonds','of Diamonds','of Diamonds','of Diamonds','of Diamonds','of Diamonds','of Diamonds','of Diamonds','of Diamonds','of Hearts','of Hearts','of Hearts','of Hearts','of Hearts','of Hearts','of Hearts','of Hearts','of Hearts','of Hearts','of Hearts','of Hearts','of Hearts','of Spades','of Spades','of Spades','of Spades','of Spades','of Spades','of Spades','of Spades','of Spades','of Spades','of Spades','of Spades','of Spades']
shuffle(cardranks)
shuffle(cardsuits)
for a,b in zip(cardranks,cardsuits):
    response = (input ('Would you like to draw a random card? (yes/no)'))
    if response == yes:
        return (a,b)
```

when I run this piece of program it says that yes is not defined and so I don't know how to continue.

Thank you

Comment: Unrelated to your syntax error, but careful with the way you are shuffling the cards.  You can end up with, for example, two or more Ace of Spades this way

Answer (score 1):

input delivers a string, so you have to check if you receive the string 'yes' not just yes. yes is not a value or variable.

also minor detail for best practice: i like that you give good variable names, but response is spelled with s ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you check if response(You spelled response wrong) is equal to yes, You are comparing it to a undefined variable of 'yes' what you need to do is:

```
#The '.upper()' bit changes the response string to uppercase.
if response.upper() == 'YES': #Yes must be in quotes to be a string comparison.
    print('Its Working!') #Prints out Its Working! to the Python IDE.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose `yes` in quotes: `'yes'` - as it is right now you're telling the Python interpreter to compare it to the value contained in the *variable* `yes` and not the *literal string* `'yes'`. It is also a good idea to make the check case-insensitive by converting `response` to lower-case:

```
response = input ('Would you like to draw a random card? (yes/no)')
if response.lower() == 'yes':
    # Return the card
```

Then there are a few other issues with your code:

1. The for-loop will keep on running if the user doesn't want to draw a card. This means that you will have to input *no* 52 times before the loop ends and the function returns without drawing a card.
2. `zip(cardranks,cardsuits)` will not give you a valid, normal deck after shuffling `cardranks` and `cardsuits` - you may end up with a deck that has 4 aces of spades and no aces of any other suit for example.

A better solution would be this:

```
# All possible ranks
cardranks = ['Ace','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','Jack','Queen','King']
# All possible suits
cardsuits = ['of Clubs','of Diamonds','of Hearts','of Spades']

# The complete deck
deck = list(itertools.product(cardranks, cardsuits))

# Shuffle the deck
random.shuffle(deck)

# Draw a random card from the deck (the deck doesn't need to be shuffled before)
rank, suit = random.choice(deck)
```

Comment: or just `[(rank, suit) for rank in cardranks for suit in cardsuits]` without using `itertools`